# Chinese cannot show correctly in Robot Framework HTML log

Tags: robotframework

When I execute the test on the Robot Framework, the Chinese log cannot show correctly in Robot Framework HTML log, but when I execute my test on the Eclipse, it shows well, can anyone tell me why? Below is the logs
[image: Robot Framework log]

[image: Eclipse log]

Answer (score 0):

Seems Eclipse handles UTF-8 encoding properly, HTML5 also supports as default UTF-8 if no other encoding is specified.

If you view html report in web browser,check html code for encoding such as : `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">` and remove it or set to `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

If screenshot was done in RIDE,UTF-8 support may be lacking or at least be problematic.

Comment: the screenshot is taken in HTML log file, the encoding in html is <meta charset="utf-8" />,  but the Chinese still could not show correctly

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by change the output string to unicode

Comment: how to change the output string to unicode?